# Transfer of list and view from development server to production server

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to transfer my list a from  development server to production server. Please guide with steps.

Comment: You can use 3rd party softwares for migration. Various tools are available in the market.

Comment: please suggest a few or are they paid

Comment: You can try Sharegate tool. It gives 15 days free trial. https://en.share-gate.com/

Comment: is there any free tool available. I have microsoft community edition 2017 but do not know how to do it?

Comment: Dear Mr Gandhi, please reply

Comment: I don't know about free tools but you can use free trials for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can always save the list as template with or without contents from list settings. So the list will be available now as template file. You can download this file from List Templates option available under galleries of site settings. Upload this file to List Templates under galleries of production site.

Now try to create a New List. The template file will be available as an option ;)